# kube-apiserver crashes periodically with configured http (insecure) connection

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes

I've set up kubernetes v1.2.4  (also tried v1.3.0-beta.2) on AWS according to http://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/aws/.

Then I changed on master node configuration of kube-apiserver to be able to access it via http by adding to  `/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.manifest`:

```
--cors-allowed-origins=.* 
--insecure-bind-address=0.0.0.0 
--insecure-port=8888
```

After this changes I can make requests via http, but a few minutes later server stops responding and I see in `kube-apiserver.log` exceptions like this:

```
I0628 19:38:18.459293       7 handlers.go:152] GET /api/v1/watch/services?resourceVersion=50104&timeoutSeconds=378: (611.892µs) 410
goroutine 349 [running]:
k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/httplog.(*respLogger).recordStatus(0xc209296150, 0x19a)
        /go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/httplog/log.go:214 +0xa6
k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/httplog.(*respLogger).WriteHeader(0xc209296150, 0x19a)
        /go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/httplog/log.go:193 +0x32
k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/apiserver/metrics.(*responseWriterDelegator).WriteHeader(0xc208d5bbc0, 0x19a)
        /go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/apiserver/metrics/metrics.go:117 +0x53
k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/apiserver.writeNegotiated(0x7f5b6e2cf368, 0xc2083e13e0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x1d4da80, 0x2, 0x7f5b6e1246d8, 0xc2085ebf28, 0xc2092420d0, 0x19a, ...)
        /go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/apiserver/apiserver.go:429 +0x174
k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/apiserver.errorNegotiated(0x7f5b6e2c27b8, 0xc209298180, 0x7f5b6e2cf368, 0xc2083e13e0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x1d4da80, 0x2, 0x7f5b6e1246d8, 0xc2085ebf28, ...)
        /go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/apiserver/apiserver.go:441 +0xdd
k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/apiserver.(*RequestScope).err(0xc2085244e0, 0x7f5b6e2c27b8, 0xc209298180, 0x7f5b6e1246d8, 0xc2085ebf28, 0xc2092420d0)
        /go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/apiserver/resthandler.go:84 +0x11f
k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/apiserver.func·027(0xc208d5bb30, 0xc20923f6e0)
        /go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/apiserver/resthandler.go:295 +0x1055
k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/apiserver/metrics.func·001(0xc208d5bb30, 0xc20923f6e0)
        /go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/apiserver/metrics/metrics.go:101 +0x269
github.com/emicklei/go-restful.(*Container).dispatch(0xc2083dcc60, 0x7f5b6e124380, 0xc209296150, 0xc2092420d0)
        /go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/Godeps/_workspace/src/github.com/emicklei/go-restful/container.go:249 +0xf5e
github.com/emicklei/go-restful.*Container.(github.com/emicklei/go-re [[kubelet/v1.2.4 (linux/amd64) kubernetes/3eed1e3] 172.20.0.184:56673]
```

Logs are for v1.2.4.

But a few minutes later when kube-apiserver restarted, I can get responses again for a minute, and the same outage repeats again.

The instance CPU Load is less then 10%. Memory:

```
$ free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:           998        752        246         16        169        370
-/+ buffers/cache:        211        787
```

Could you explain what's going on here and why it happens?

Comment: Just wondering if you might have too little memory: Can you check that?

Comment: @Norbert: updated info in the question. Looks like there is some free memory.

Comment: 1GB is not a lot. Up it to 4GB and retry the stack (Usually you would query a pod with `kubectl describe pod` but with your api server itself being the container crashing, that is not going to work right now)